# Using van de Wiele's characterization as a definition?

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, computability-theory

This fall I'm teaching a class on generalized computability theory (broadly construed). One thing I want to talk about briefly is [E-recursion](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~sacks/erecint.pdf).

Now, E-recursion is generally defined in terms of the *Normann schemes* (independently introduced by Moschovakis); these give a Kleene-type definition, where E-recursive functions are built up from basic functions via the rules in the schemes. In conversations however (and for myself), I've found this specific collection of schemes somewhat hard to motivate - why should we believe that we've found the "right" scheme? (E.g. how confident are we that we won't tomorrow find some new rule for generating "recursive" functions which is "clearly" correct?)

That's a reasonable question for mathoverflow, but it's not the one I'm asking here. There is an alternate characterization of E-recursion given by van de Wiele (and later re-proved and generalized by Slaman and others): briefly, "E-recursive" is the same as "uniformly $\Sigma_1$ on admissible sets." Once we accept admissibility as something natural, uniform $\Sigma_1$-definability on admissible sets seems pretty well motivated to me.

Right now I'm planning on teaching E-recursion ahistorically - definining it a la van de Wiele, and then presenting the (actual) definition via Normann schemes as a theorem. (*Besides being possibly more easily motivated, it also lets me transition quickly to E-recursion from admissibility.*) I'm thinking now about the order in which I might present results:

> Are there any reasonably-simple-to-state results in E-recursion which are proved more easily via uniform $\Sigma_1$ definability on admissible sets, than by the Normann schemes?

Basically, I'm wondering if I should present the Normann schemes immediately after the van de Wiele-style definition, or whether I can prove some basic results in between. *Note that the Normann schemes are very clearly uniformly $\Sigma_1$ on admissible sets, so I suspect the kind of results I'm looking for would be positive rather than negative (since they will flow more easily from a stronger definition).*

Comment: Please do write notes and post them online. :-)

Comment: I was going to request the same, Andres, but you beat me to it.